# Excel 1004 Runtime Error when Sorting Table

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

Good Afternoon Stack Overflow Patrons:

I, like many others, are getting the dreaded 1004 Runtime Error when attempting to sort a table... but here is the kicker.... the macro works when you manually go to Developer > Macros and run the macro.

The macro is intended to sort data inside a table named "Compiled_Data" in four steps: First it sorts by Date Oldest to Newest (data is in column A), then it sorts by Contractor Name alphabetically (data is in column B), then by Customer Name (Data in column C), and then by description (Data in column D).

Here is the macro (created by Recording):

```
    Sub Sort_Compiled_Data_Sheet()

        Sheets("Compiled_Data").Activate
        Range("A3").Select
        Range("A4").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data").ListObjects("Compiled_Data").Sort. _
            SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data").ListObjects("Compiled_Data").Sort. _
            SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data").ListObjects("Compiled_Data").Sort. _
            SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Contractor]"), SortOn:= _
            xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data").ListObjects("Compiled_Data").Sort. _
            SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Customer]"), SortOn:= _
            xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data").ListObjects("Compiled_Data").Sort. _
            SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Item]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data").ListObjects("Compiled_Data"). _
            Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
       End With
```

So, like I said the code works great when manually run.  However, when I call the macro to run from using a second macro, I get the dreaded Run-Time error 1004 on the ".apply" line each and every time.

I use a Master Macro to run the Sort_Compiled_Data_Sheet macro using the following code:

```
    Sub MASTER_MACRO()
        Application.Run "Fill_Compiled_Data_Sheet"
        Application.Run "Sort_Compiled_Data_Sheet"
        Application.Run "Column_Width_All_Sheets"
    End Sub
```

Every time I use the MASTER_MACRO to run the Sort_Compiled_Data_Sheet macro, I get the run time error on the ".apply" line.

Does anyone know how to get past this error, and why does it error at the ".apply" sorting step when called by a second macro but work when manually run?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Sort_Compiled_Data_Sheet()

     Dim sht as worksheet

     Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiled_Data")

     sht.Activate

     With sht.ListObjects("Compiled_Data").Sort

        .SortFields.Clear

        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending

        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Contractor]"), _
                         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending


        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Customer]"), _
                            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending

        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Compiled_Data[Item]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending


         .Header = xlYes
         .MatchCase = False
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Apply

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your assistance.  Apparently people running Excel 2007, it works great.  But running on Excel 2010 with both Win7 and Win8, we are getting the error on the original macro.  I'll try your edit and respond back with comment.

Comment: Tim, sorry, using your code still returns the Runtime error, highlighting the .Apply line (3rd line of code from end).  This was tested on a Win7 machine using Office 2010, and a Win8 machine using Office 2010.  It did however work on a Win8 machine using Office365.

Comment: I'm on Excel 2010, Win7

Comment: Well humpf.... I simply don't know then.  Not sure why it works on some machines (yours), and not on the ones here in the office.