# Excel VBA Sort, error 1004 on .Apply

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I'm having issues using sort in VBA. I saw this thread for which **the answers don't work for me**: [Sort in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140221/excel-1004-runtime-error-when-sorting-table)

I believe there is a maximum nr of records on which you can sort. Is that correct? I want to sort on 4 criteria in a sheet/table with *188,000* records. 
I always get an error on the `.Apply` statement: `"run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error"`

#### Below my code:

```
Sub Sort_Table()

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    sht.Activate

    With sht.ListObjects("Table1").Sort

        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,    Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Country Code]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Rating]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Segment]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Potential problem

Actually maybe you shouldn't the `Apply` inside the `With` since your object is really updated after the end of the `With` block.
For instance here your parameters (`.SortFields` etc ...) are not yet set when you use `Apply`. I'm not 100% sure because I doesn't have EXCEL to test right now, and it seem not everyone have this problem with this code as you pointed out, but that may be a reason.

#### (potential) Solution

Try doing:

```
With sht.ListObjects("Table1").Sort

    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,    Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Country Code]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Rating]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Segment]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending ', DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin

End With

sht.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.Apply
```

Tell me if this doesn't solve the issue

#### Other potential problems/solutions

- The sheet you work on (Sorting) is protected
- Check out this question: [Excel VBA Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434817/excel-vba-sort-error-when-automated-from-access-2007)

Hope it helped anyway ...