# Selection sorting not working as expected on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I need to just sort the selection I am making in one Excel Datasheet. This book is shared and I am trying to not to avoid the users to use the filter/sort option instead to use this small procedure.

I just tried in many ways to approach it: by macro record, by myself, googling and documenting in any possible way.

Input: Any selection possible in one Excel sheet with headers.

Expected ouptut: Alphabetical sorting of the selection.

Trial 1: Macro recording

```
Option Explicit  

Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "IV71"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
        .SetRange Range("IV72:IZ78")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

That code works, but obvious, I need to custom for my selection:

```
Option Explicit  

Sub Macro1()
Dim MyRange as Range
Set MyRange = Selection

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=MyRange,  _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
        .SetRange MyRange 
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

On that one, I got a 1004 error on .Apply. So I modified to:

```
Option Explicit  

Sub Macro1()
Dim MyRange as Range
Set MyRange = Selection

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=MyRange,  _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
        .SetRange MyRange 
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.Apply
End Sub
```

Same result:  I got a 1004 error on .Apply

Then I remove the range declaration:

```
Option Explicit  

Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Selection,  _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
        .SetRange Selection 
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.Apply
End Sub
```

It is becoming weird... whatever options I try and checked it is reporting error 1004, directly it is not working or it is reporting that the section defined can not be on blank (when it is not). [Idea 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037735/excel-vba-sort-error-1004-on-apply) [Idea 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140221/excel-1004-runtime-error-when-sorting-table) [Idea 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434817/excel-vba-sort-error-when-automated-from-access-2007) [Idea 4](https://trumpexcel.com/sort-data-vba/) [Idea 5](https://www.thesmallman.com/sorting-with-vba) [Idea 6](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-to-apply-and-control-autofilter-in-excel/) [Check 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff840646(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) [Check 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sort.apply) [Check 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection) [Check 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection)

My only concern is if, maybe, as Selection is a object, maybe, setting it as range is failing.

One additional detail... This procedure is working just when I select one column... the problem is when I select 2 or more.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Strange you don't recieve an erro 91 on your `MyRange = Selection`. When the selection is made on the tab `"Raw Data"`, you need to actually `Set` your range object > `Set MyRange = Selection` as this worked for me. However I do recommend to apply more direct references.

Comment: And furthermore, the only time I am able to re-create the 1004 error is when your selection is actually made outside the references sheet. Hence the importance of the point made in my first comment on using more direct references.

Comment: Sorry... I already edit the post. I have some versions with `Range = Selection`, that fails, and some with `Set Range = Selection`, I copy the wrong one. Anyhow, the error I am having are related to the Set version. How to make a direct reference on `Selection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, anyhow, still I don´t know why I have this problem.
I can not order many columns in a range if I am not splitting in columns separately.
It is not the best one, but works... maybe need some cleaning.

```
Option Explicit  

Sub Macro1()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim FirstCol As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SelAddress As String
Dim Aux As String

Set MyRange = Selection
SelAddress = Selection.Address

SelAddress = Mid(SelAddress, 2, Len(SelAddress) - InStr(1, SelAddress, "$", vbBinaryCompare))
Aux = Mid(SelAddress, 1, InStr(1, SelAddress, "$", vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
SelAddress = Mid(SelAddress, Len(Aux) + 2, Len(SelAddress) - Len(Aux))
Aux = Aux & Mid(SelAddress, 1, InStr(1, SelAddress, "$", vbBinaryCompare) - 2)

FirstCol = Range(Aux).Column
FirstRow = Range(Aux).Row

SelAddress = Mid(Selection.Address, Len(Aux) + 5, Len(SelAddress) - Len(Aux))
Aux = Mid(SelAddress, 1, InStr(1, SelAddress, "$", vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
SelAddress = Mid(SelAddress, Len(Aux) + 2, Len(SelAddress) - Len(Aux))
Aux = Aux & Mid(SelAddress, InStr(1, SelAddress, "$", vbBinaryCompare) + 1, Len(SelAddress))

LastCol = Range(Aux).Column
LastRow = Range(Aux).Row


For i = FirstCol To LastCol Step 1
    Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(FirstRow, i), Cells(LastRow, i))
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=MyRange, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
        .SetRange MyRange
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next


End Sub
```

Hope it helps!